# animated \tikzmarknode in a slide with beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, tikz-node

I have put in my beamer slide as

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\tikzstyle{nb}= [] % [baseline=10.5ex]
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{equation*}
 \tikzmarknode[circle,draw=red,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment
length=1pt,amplitude=0.4pt}]{p}{$A$}  = B ;
\end{equation*}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like that the red circle appears in a second moment, after pressing the "enter button2". This is clear with items, but I am not able to figure it out with tikzmarknode.

thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Please. Give a MWE with your unworking solutions.

Comment: You are right. sorry. For example, I have tried to add <1> in different position, mimicking what I usually do with items.

Comment: You should add a code that can be compiled.

Comment: @projetmbc Sorry. I have just added it

Comment: Interesting. I appear to have overlooked making tikzmarknode beamer-aware. I'll fix that.  However, I'm not sure that that would do what you want.  Is it just the circle that should change, or the contents of the node as well?

Comment: Incidentally, tikzmarknode _should_ pick up on the math mode so you shouldn't need the dollars inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\tikzmarknode` is not beamer-aware.  That's an oversight, and one that I will correct in the next release.  (It is, however, math-aware which means that it picks up on the math mode that it is in and implements that in the node so you don't need the dollars inside.)  However, it might not be that you want a fully beamer-aware version of `\tikzmarknode` here as it depends slightly on what you want to do with it.  I suspect that what you actually want is provided by the `overlay-beamer-styles` library which provides ways to make TikZ styles beamer-aware.  Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593958/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  arrows,
  shapes,
  backgrounds,
  tikzmark,
  calc,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  patterns,
  overlay-beamer-styles %% <-- use this library
}

% \tikzstyle is depreciated
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={remember picture},
  na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},
  nb/.style={baseline=10.5ex}
}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{equation*}
 \tikzmarknode[circle,draw=red]{p}{$A$}  = B ;
\end{equation*}

% To show the effect of removing the dollars
\begin{equation*}
 \tikzmarknode[circle,draw=red]{p}{A}  = B ;
\end{equation*}

% Hide the *whole* node on slide 1
\begin{equation*}
\tikzmarknode[circle,draw=red,visible on=<2>]{p}{A}  = B ;
\end{equation*}

% Only hide the outer circle on slide 1
\begin{equation*}
\tikzmarknode[circle,alt=<2>{draw=red}{}]{p}{A}  = B ;
\end{equation*}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Incidentally, I kept getting math overflow errors with the random steps so I removed it for this example.