# Handwriting path with TikZ in Beamer (path decoration?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-decorations

I am building a handwritten style presentation. I would like to have all the features very similar to handwritten. As you can see from my example, I am almost able to do that. The problem is the path in the Ti*k*Z framework. As you can notice, the key words given for tikzmarknode seem not to work for "path".

So my questions are: 1) Is it possible to have the arrow looking as the tikzmarknode? 2) If yes, where am I wrong?

I have indeed the feeling that "decorations.pathmorphing" could work also for the path.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593958/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  arrows,
  shapes,
  backgrounds,
  tikzmark,
  calc,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  patterns,
  overlay-beamer-styles %% <-- use this library
}

% \tikzstyle is depreciated
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={remember picture},
  na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},
  nb/.style={baseline=10.5ex}
}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{equation*}
\tikzmarknode[circle,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=1pt},alt=<2>{draw=red,line width=0.5mm, minimum size=20pt}{}]{p2}{A}  = B ;
\end{equation*}


\tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};Hello
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->,red,line width=0.5mm,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=10pt}]<2-> (n1) edge [bend left] (p2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74881/1952?

Comment: yes. It is not in the beamer framework.

Comment: @Ignasi: you have killed my questions

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your decoration instructions to the `edge` instead of the `path`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593958/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  arrows,
  shapes,
  backgrounds,
  tikzmark,
  calc,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  patterns,
  overlay-beamer-styles %% <-- use this library
}

% \tikzstyle is depreciated
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={remember picture},
  na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},
  nb/.style={baseline=10.5ex}
}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tikzset{na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}

\begin{equation*}
\tikzmarknode[circle,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=1pt},alt=<2>{draw=red,line width=0.5mm, minimum size=20pt}{}]{p2}{A}  = B ;
\end{equation*}


\tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};Hello
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->,red,line width=0.5mm]<2-> (n1) edge [bend left,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=2pt}] (p2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]